# What is general term of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $$a_1=-1,a_2=0,a_3=7,a_4=26,....$$ be a sequence. What is $a_n$?

Comment: There are many different sequences that start with those 4 numbers.

Comment: @arkeet- For example??

Comment: I love this games!

Comment: I have a sequence $b_1 = 0, b_2 = 0, b_3 = 0, b_4 = 0$. What is $b_5$? Why of course it is $24$, for I have chosen $b_n = n^4-10 n^3+35 n^2-50 n+24$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=-1%2C0%2C7%2C26&go=Search gives an answer (with reversed signs)

Comment: @Henry - Thanks for this site.

Comment: What is the next term in this series: $a_0=1, a_1=1, a_2=1$? Well, obviously $a_3=-17$, as $a_n=(n+1)^n-n^{n+1}$.

Comment: These kind of questions are kind of stupid. Because you can have many different formulas for $a_n$ so that the first few terms are the given numbers. For eg: see the one given in the answer below and my comment for that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_1=0^3-1=-1$$
$$a_2=1^3-1=0$$
$$a_3=2^3-1=7$$
$$a_4=3^3-1=26$$
So
$$a_n=(n-1)^3-1$$

But I have to admit that theoretically speaking, it has infinite many solutions since you can use any polynomials to approach it.

Comment: How about $a_n=(n-1)^3-1+(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$?

Comment: I have to admit that theoretically speaking, it has infinite many solutions since you can use any polynomials to approach it.

Comment: Ya, so you can't say $a_n$ is your formula. Better if you change your answer.